# XCode13.4 run old flutter project failed to build iOS app

Tags: ios, flutter

I just upgraded to Xcode 13.4 in macOS Monterey 12.4, running a flutter project got this error:

```
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: No such file or directory
Command: /Users/taoli-blue/fvm/versions/2.10.3/bin/flutter assemble --no-version-check --output=/Users/taoli-blue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fjqqglukmistzcemtudzjrvxvsvk/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/ -dTargetPlatform=ios -dTargetFile=/Users/taoli-blue/taoli/flutter_taoli_app/lib/main_dev.dart -dBuildMode=debug -dIosArchs=arm64 -dSdkRoot=/Applications/Xcode13.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk -dSplitDebugInfo= -dTreeShakeIcons=false -dTrackWidgetCreation=true -dDartObfuscation= -dEnableBitcode= --ExtraGenSnapshotOptions= --DartDefines= --ExtraFrontEndOptions= -dCodesignIdentity=21E6A88880ED32FA5B3525F5134308364DAB1434 debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets
_ProcessImpl._runAndWait (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:487:7)
_runNonInteractiveProcessSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:632:18)
Process.runSync (dart:io-patch/process_patch.dart:68:12)
Context.runSync (file:///Users/taoli-blue/fvm/versions/2.10.3/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:92:42)
Context.buildApp (file:///Users/taoli-blue/fvm/versions/2.10.3/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:448:34)
Context.run (file:///Users/taoli-blue/fvm/versions/2.10.3/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:51:9)
main (file:///Users/taoli-blue/fvm/versions/2.10.3/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:17:5)
delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:32)
RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

And I totally don't know how to resolve this error.
Any one could help me?
```

Comment: Fixed, it was my Xcode path configuration problem

Comment: How did you solve this?